# I can´t get my divs to line up perfectly (vertical)

Tags: html, css

edit: Made it by adding margin-bottom to the overlay.

I cant get my divs to line up perfectly, here´s the screenshot of it:

[image]

```css
.imgWrap {
    position:relative; 
    display:inline-block;
    opacity: 0.85;
        }
.imgWrap img {
    display:block;
    margin-left: 25px;
        }
.imgWrap:after {
    content:""; 
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0;
    background:linear-gradient(transparent, darkred);
    margin-left: 50px;
        }
.imgWrap:hover:after {
    display:none;
    margin-left: 50px;
        }
        .svart{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    float:left;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: .2em;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

img.inni{
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com/content/media/items/avatar/220px/9ec68cc6081481151513.png">
                 <p>1 key</div>

             <div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com/content/media/items/avatar/220px/e3a37efb651475612008.png">
                 <p>7 cases // 1 key</div>

             <div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com//content/media/items/avatar/220px/2aa4fb89721474239225.png">
                 <p>3 cases // 1 key</div>

             <p>
             <div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com//content/media/items/avatar/220px/5975237f541474239197.png">
                 <p>7 cases // 1 key</div>

             <div class="imgWrap"><div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com//content/media/items/avatar/220px/75e8bb7e5d1473412157.png"><p>2 keys</div></div>

             <div class="imgWrap"><div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com/content/media/items/avatar/220px/8d04eb69ff1473412255.png"><p>1 key</div></div>

             <div class="imgWrap"><div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com//content/media/items/avatar/220px/7bd39778fe1473412354.png"><p>1 key</div></div>

              <div class="imgWrap"><div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com//content/media/items/avatar/220px/fa26b845f91473412371.png"><p>1 key</div></div>

              <div class="imgWrap"><div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com//content/media/items/avatar/220px/97eb34e7631475683880.png"><p>1-2 keys</div></div>

             <div class="imgWrap"><div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com/content/media/items/avatar/220px/6db50395201481302229.png"><p>7-8 keys</div></div>
```

Things i´ve tried:

I made the red overlay the height of the div svart, 150px, but that just made 1 icon place blank.
https://jsfiddle.net/n5tp97ug/

Comment: Could you what you mean when you say they don't align properly?  Do you mean where the red overlay appears not directly over the image behind it?

Comment: You might want to close those `<p>` tags. It is not causing your issue but could cause some more down the road.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a simple float:left; to your .imgWrap class.  I tested the fiddle and it works.  Everything else stays the same.

```
.imgWrap {
    position:relative; 
    display:inline-block;
    opacity: 0.85;
    float:left;
        }
```

The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it.

Here is a good website that explains how float works:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow! You might consider adding some explanation on why this works as well to assist the OP in understanding not just how to fix it, but why the fix works.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your fiddle.. the misalign is coming from the `display:inline-block` within imgWrap.  Would it be possible to remove that class and add another class to svart?  That way it inherits the positioning of svart and you can just overide the background with your new class.

Example:

```
//this div will have a black background
<div class="svart"></div>
//this div will have the gradient background    
<div class="svart myClass"></div>
<style type="text/css">
.svart {
background: black;
}
.svart.myClass {
background:linear-gradient(transparent, darkred);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote most of your CSS but kept everything the way you wanted it. I simplified a lot of the CSS as well as some things weren't needed like the `.imgWrap` element.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n5tp97ug/5/)

By default the `<div class="row">` element is block and will take up 100% of the width of its parent. We can use this to get get the `<div class="svart">` elements to auto break to the next line when there's no more room. We don't need to use floats all we need to use is `margin: 0 10px 10px` and `display: inline-block;`.

Also, there's no need for the `.imgWrap` element as we can move the hover state and background color over to the `.active` class for `.svart`;

As for the problem you're facing with your original code it was likely a mix of the floats, and margins you have to try and position your red gradient and spacing between the boxes.

```css
.svart {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px;
  padding: 8px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.svart.active:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent, darkred);
  border-radius: 5px;
  content: '';
}
.svart.active:hover:after {
  display: none;
}
.svart .inni {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="svart active">
    <img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com/content/media/items/avatar/220px/9ec68cc6081481151513.png" />
    <p>
      1 key
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="svart">
    <img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com/content/media/items/avatar/220px/9ec68cc6081481151513.png" />
    <p>
      1 key
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- !.row -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="svart active">
    <img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com/content/media/items/avatar/220px/9ec68cc6081481151513.png" />
    <p>
      1 key
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="svart">
    <img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com/content/media/items/avatar/220px/9ec68cc6081481151513.png" />
    <p>
      1 key
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="svart">
    <img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com/content/media/items/avatar/220px/9ec68cc6081481151513.png" />
    <p>
      1 key
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="svart">
    <img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com/content/media/items/avatar/220px/9ec68cc6081481151513.png" />
    <p>
      1 key
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="svart">
    <img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com/content/media/items/avatar/220px/9ec68cc6081481151513.png" />
    <p>
      1 key
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="svart">
    <img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com/content/media/items/avatar/220px/9ec68cc6081481151513.png" />
    <p>
      1 key
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="svart">
    <img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com/content/media/items/avatar/220px/9ec68cc6081481151513.png" />
    <p>
      1 key
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- !.row -->
<!--
<div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com/content/media/items/avatar/220px/9ec68cc6081481151513.png">
  <p>1 key</p>
</div>

<div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com/content/media/items/avatar/220px/e3a37efb651475612008.png">
  <p>7 cases // 1 key</p>
</div>

<div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com//content/media/items/avatar/220px/2aa4fb89721474239225.png">
  <p>3 cases // 1 key</p>
</div>

<p>
  <div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com//content/media/items/avatar/220px/5975237f541474239197.png">
    <p>7 cases // 1 key</p>
  </div>

  <div class="imgWrap">
    <div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com//content/media/items/avatar/220px/75e8bb7e5d1473412157.png">
      <p>2 keys</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="imgWrap">
    <div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com/content/media/items/avatar/220px/8d04eb69ff1473412255.png">
      <p>1 key</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="imgWrap">
    <div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com//content/media/items/avatar/220px/7bd39778fe1473412354.png">
      <p>1 key</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="imgWrap">
    <div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com//content/media/items/avatar/220px/fa26b845f91473412371.png">
      <p>1 key</div>
  </div>

  <div class="imgWrap">
    <div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com//content/media/items/avatar/220px/97eb34e7631475683880.png">
      <p>1-2 keys</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="imgWrap">
    <div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com/content/media/items/avatar/220px/6db50395201481302229.png">
      <p>7-8 keys</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  -->
```

Answer (score 0):

also you can do it by removing the spaces between div's, inline-blocks consider space, check this https://jsfiddle.net/n5tp97ug/7/ and this blog https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

```
<div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com/content/media/items/avatar/220px/9ec68cc6081481151513.png"><p>1 key</div><div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com/content/media/items/avatar/220px/e3a37efb651475612008.png"><p>7 cases // 1 key</div><div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com//content/media/items/avatar/220px/2aa4fb89721474239225.png"><p>3 cases // 1 key</div><p><div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com//content/media/items/avatar/220px/5975237f541474239197.png"><p>7 cases // 1 key</div><div class="imgWrap"><div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com//content/media/items/avatar/220px/75e8bb7e5d1473412157.png"><p>2 keys</div></div><div class="imgWrap"><div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com/content/media/items/avatar/220px/8d04eb69ff1473412255.png"><p>1 key</div></div><div class="imgWrap"><div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com//content/media/items/avatar/220px/7bd39778fe1473412354.png"><p>1 key</div></div><div class="imgWrap"><div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com//content/media/items/avatar/220px/fa26b845f91473412371.png"><p>1 key</div></div><div class="imgWrap"><div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com//content/media/items/avatar/220px/97eb34e7631475683880.png"><p>1-2 keys</div></div><div class="imgWrap"><div class="svart"><img class="inni" src="https://rocket-league.com/content/media/items/avatar/220px/6db50395201481302229.png"><p>7-8 keys</div></div>
```